# How to change Null constraint for all columns ?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some big tables (30+ columns) with `NOT NULL` constraints. I would like to change all those constraints to `NULL`. To do it for a single column I can use

```
ALTER TABLE <your table> MODIFY <column name> NULL;
```

Is there a way to do it for all columns in one request ? Or should I copy/paste this line for all columns (><) ?

Comment: Copy-paste. But why remove these constraints? (Application code may depend on them.)

Comment: You could use PL/SQL but if you don't know the language it will be way faster to copy/paste or search/replace. You could help generating the code by selecting the columns in the system table dba_tab_cols

Comment: @jarlh Long story... I came recently on this project which has serious design problem. Most of the value are null, so this constraint must be changed.

Comment: @Aaron I will have a look (can be usefull for a next time), thanks

Comment: Hmmm, how are the values null if there is a NOT NULL constraint in place? Or do you mean "future values"?

Comment: Oups, I was not clear. Most of the values the app wants to insert are `NULL`, so this `NOT NULL` constraint is a serious design problem. Currently the app replaces the null by an empty string in some processes (this is no even a default value in the database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do it for all columns in one request ?

Yes. By (ab)using **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** in **PL/SQL**. Loop through all the columns by querying **USER_TAB_COLUMNS** view.

For example,

```
FOR i IN
( SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>' AND NULLABLE='N'
)
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> MODIFY i.COLUMN_NAME NULL';
END LOOP;
```

In my opinion, by the time you would write the PL/SQL block, you could do it much quickly by using a good **text editor**. In pure **SQL** you just need 30 queries for 30 columns.

Comment: even better would be to add `NULLABLE='N'` to your FOR cursor, skips columns which are already nullable

Comment: @Sathya hmm... this would filter out the rows. But, OP said he has all columns as NOT NULL. But, anyway it is good to add the condition. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For a single table you can issue a single `alter table` command to set the listed columns to allow `null`, which is a little more efficient than running one at a time, but you still have to list every column.

```
alter table ...
modify (
  col1 null,
  col1 null,
  col3 null);
```

If you were applying `not null` constraints then this would be more worthwhile, as they require a scan of the table to ensure that no nulls are present, and (I think) an exclusive table lock.

Answer (score 1):

You can query `user_tab_cols` and combine it with a FOR cursor & EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to modify all not null columns - the PL/SQL block for doing like that would look like so:

```
DECLARE
  v_sql_statement  VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  FOR table_recs IN (SELECT table_name, column_name
                       FROM user_tab_cols
                      WHERE nullable = 'N') LOOP
    v_sql_statement :=
      'ALTER TABLE ' || table_recs.table_name || ' MODIFY ' || table_recs.column_name || ' NULL';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_statement;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If you want to do it for *all* columns in a database instead of the ones in current schema, you can replace user_tab_cols and put in dba_tab_cols; I'd just run the query in the FOR to ensure that the columns being fetched are indeed the correct ones to be modified